# Prolog flatten accumulator vs hole

Tags: prolog

I can't understand the difference between accumulators and holes.

Formally:

```
Accumulators
*Use 2 arguments to organize the building of some
output structure
*One is for result so far
*One is for final result

Holes
*Use 2 arguments to organize the building of some
output structure
*One is for final result
*One for a hole in the final result where further information can be put
```

Is this flattener using a hole or an accumulator?
How do I convert it to use the other one?

```
my_flatten(In,[],Out).
my_flatten([],Acc,Acc).
my_flatten([H|T],Acc,Out) :-
    my_flatten(T,Acc,TOut),
    my_flatten(H,TOut,Out).
my_flatten(X,Acc,[X|Acc]) :-
    X \= [],
    X \= [_|_].
```

Answer (score 2):

Accumulators are variables that are used in recursion to count or build a structure such as a conventional list. Holes are used in difference lists (Or other difference structures), where a list is represented as a pair of terms, the front and the back. Often the back would be a variable or a hole. It is usual to use an infix notation so a list would be:
      `Front-Back`

So `List = [a,b,c|Hole]-Hole` for example.

Using difference lists allows you to have constant time appending by just rearranging variables.

In difference notation `L-L` is the empty list, `[1|Z]-Z` is the list containing 1, and `[1,2,3|Z]-Z` is the list containing 1,2 and 3. You can rectify a difference list by unifying it with `Y-[]`.

Flatten in difference notation is given as worksheet 28 in  'Clause and effect - by W.F.Clocksin'

```
flatten(X,Y):-flatpair(X,Y-[]) %rectifying the list

flatpair([],L-L). %empty list
flatpair([H|T],L1-L3):-flatpair(H,L1-L2),flatpair(T,L2-L3).
flatpair(X,[X|Z]-Z).
```

Which is much more efficient then using accumulators and constructing partial lists or using append.

Comment: It might be worth explicitly noting that a common way to write `flatpair` would be to forgo the infix `-` notation and use a separate argument to "fill the hole", *e.g.*, `flatpair([], L, L). flatpair([H|T], L1, L3) :- flatpair(H, L1, L2), flatpair(T, L2, L3). flatpair(X, [X|Z], Z).` One doesn't need to be fixated on infix notation to implement holes. :)

Comment: `flatpair([],L-[]).` has two solutions: `L = [] ;
L = [[]].`